# In angularjs where should I store ui configuration values

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm trying to figure out the best practices for storing UI configuration values in angular js - in this instance I'm using Kendo UI - my screen has 10 or so grids (in tabs) the bulk of the code in my controller is just configuration details for the grids, column settings, pagination etc... so it looks like this

```
 $scope.gridonecolumns = [{
                        field: "ContactName",
                        title: "Contact Name",
                        width: 140
                    }, {
                        field: "ContactTitle",
                        title: "Contact Title",
                        width: 190
                    }, {
                        field: "CompanyName",
                        title: "Company Name"
                    }, {
                        field: "Country",
                        width: 110
                    }]

$scope.gridtwocolumns = [{
                        field: "BlahBlah",
                        title: "Blah Blah",
                        width: 140
                    }, {
                        field: "YesYes",
                        title: "Yes Yes",
                        width: 190
                    }, {
                        field: "SomeField",
                        title: "Company Name"
                    }, {
                        field: "Country",
                        width: 110
                    }]
```

and so on

I was thinking of just placing them into a service as there 'may' come a time that I need to store them and am curious what others have done to keep the controller code 'clean' of these configuration type items.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you think your data is going to be shared by different controllers you should definitely put it in a service. I have lots of similar services (label, variable name groups) in my apps.